# Всплывающая строка-подсказка с репутацией пользователя не переведена

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Если в комментариях навести указатель на имя любого пользователя то увидим строку вида: "12356 reputation", а не ожидаемое "12356 репутации".

Comment: Проверка связи.